# Enabling compilation-shell-minor-mode in GUD (for next-error)

Tags: gud, compilation-mode

I want to see stack trace lines highlighted in GUD and have `next-error` work there.  That works for me if, after starting GUD (via `M-x pdb`) I enable `compilation-shell-minor-mode`.

However, if I do this:

```
(add-hook 'pdb-mode-hook (lambda () (compilation-shell-minor-mode t)))
```

Then when I run `M-x pdb`, I get that minor mode enabled, but the matching error lines in the buffer don't get highlighted.  I then have to disable and re-enable the minor mode to get the highlighting back.

How can I configure things so that the minor mode works fully as soon as I start GUD?

Comment: I am not sure why the highlighting doesn't work for you initially: for me it does. It worked with your snippet, but also you could try simply: `(add-hook 'pdb-mode-hook 'compilation-shell-minor-mode)`. From the documentation on `compilation-shell-minor-mode`: "If called from
Lisp, enable the mode if ARG is omitted or nil"

Comment: I'm not sure why this didn't work for me back then, I believe it works fine now :-/